# Visualizing trend in ordinal ranking data

Tags: data-visualization, ordinal-data, normalization, ranking, trend

## The Setup

There are 18 balls, named A through R.
They continuously and randomly (or so it seems) increase/decrease in size due to certain external factors.

There is a black box system that measures the increase/decrease in size of the 18 balls at regular intervals t<sub>x</sub>.
For each interval, it outputs the changes in size of the 18 balls.
However, it does not output the absolute changes.
Instead, it outputs the **ranking** of the balls, in accordance to those changes.

For each interval t<sub>x</sub>, there are 3 outputs:

1) The ranking of the balls that have **increased** in size, from greatest increase to lowest increase.
2) The balls that are **unchanged** in size (neutral or 0 size change).
3) The ranking of the balls that have **decreased** in size, from greatest decrease to lowest decrease.

Examples of the 3 outputs for a certain interval:

1. Size increased

   ```
   Ball   Rank
   C      1  ---> biggest increase
   I      2
   N      3
   K      4
   B      5
   F      6
   E      7  ---> smallest increase
   ```
2. Size unchanged

   ```
   Ball   Rank
   L      0
   P      0
   ```
3. Size decreased

   ```
   Ball   Rank
   A      1  ---> biggest decrease
   D      2
   R      3
   H      4
   M      5
   Q      6
   J      7
   O      8
   G      9  ---> smallest decrease
   ```

The 3 outputs combined

```
Ball   Rank
C      1   ---> biggest increase
I      2
N      3
K      4
B      5
F      6
E      7
L      0   ---> neutral
P      0   ---> neutral
G      -9
O      -8
J      -7
Q      -6
M      -5
H      -4
R      -3
D      -2
A      -1  ---> biggest decrease
```

*Note: I've made the numbers negative for the 'size decreased' ranking, for clarity and to be able to distinguish them from the 'size increased' ranking numbers.*

## The Question

How can the trend of the increase/decrease in size for each ball be visualized?

So, if a ball is always ranked as 1st for increasing in size, the chart should show a steady increasing trend.

Maybe the data first needs to be normalized to values between -1 and +1?
As for the neutral rankings (zero increase/decrease), I'm not sure.
Should that show as the zero line in the chart?
Or maybe as a 'horizontal line' (rate of change = zero), continuing the previous trend-point?

Can't seem to find an approach for this visualization.

If someone has an idea about this, I'll try to implement it in Excel, Python or R.

## The Data

Here you can find a part of the dataset that I need to visualize.

*Note: I've made the numbers negative for the 'size decreased' ranking, for clarity and to be able to distinguish them from the 'size increased' ranking numbers.*

Raw data (with title row, delimited by semicolon)

```
Ball;t1;t2;t3;t4;t5;t6;t7;t8;t9;t10;t11;t12;t13;t14;t15;t16;t17;t18;t19;t20;t21;t22;t23;t24;t25;t26;t27;t28;t29;t30;t31;t32;t33;t34;t35;t36;t37;t38;t39;t40;t41;t42;t43;t44;t45;t46;t47;t48;t49;t50
A;1;1;1;-3;-1;-6;0;4;-5;1;1;-17;0;-17;-18;-3;-14;-8;0;-2;-3;-2;-1;-1;1;3;1;1;15;-1;0;2;1;1;3;1;3;1;1;7;13;-2;-1;-5;4;-3;7;1;1;1
B;5;-6;-7;8;5;6;6;5;6;-15;-12;-12;-10;-11;-4;-5;-16;-6;-6;-11;-10;-4;-7;-14;0;-5;16;14;12;13;10;9;10;14;9;11;11;6;12;15;11;9;-7;8;11;-2;-6;-4;-4;11
C;-7;0;5;1;1;3;1;2;5;2;-11;-13;-8;-14;-17;-15;-12;-11;-13;-6;-11;-5;-8;-3;8;4;7;11;6;4;8;7;7;11;1;5;5;8;6;6;5;3;3;9;12;1;6;7;4;8
D;4;0;-2;-4;-2;-2;-5;0;0;0;-6;-11;-2;-3;-11;-12;-8;-12;-4;-9;-8;-12;-5;-5;10;9;3;7;4;5;4;5;3;5;8;10;14;4;8;11;7;12;-4;-4;-6;-5;-5;-9;-6;-4
E;-5;0;-6;-6;7;9;-8;-3;-9;-4;-2;-3;-7;-7;-1;-8;-9;-17;-15;-10;-9;-11;-11;-16;12;10;13;6;5;7;9;4;2;7;5;3;7;7;3;5;14;10;9;5;-4;6;-7;-7;7;6
F;3;6;8;-8;6;5;3;0;3;-14;-15;-15;-15;-18;-12;-10;-4;-16;-14;-16;-13;-9;-9;-9;9;11;10;17;16;8;-3;10;13;12;-3;6;13;10;9;14;-3;-5;-5;4;3;3;5;6;-5;9
G;-4;-1;0;7;-9;8;0;-5;-4;-5;-9;-16;-14;-4;-13;-6;-7;-9;-12;-14;-15;-3;-14;-8;-1;-2;11;13;7;9;-2;-1;8;-2;-2;0;12;-4;7;-1;-2;0;2;0;-3;0;0;-3;-2;-1
H;8;-5;6;6;-4;-4;-6;-6;-6;-7;-5;-9;-12;-12;-3;-14;-3;-10;-7;-17;-17;-8;-12;-4;3;1;6;10;14;-3;-4;-5;12;4;4;4;8;5;4;8;3;11;-6;10;6;8;-9;5;3;2
I;7;4;3;2;2;0;-7;3;4;-12;-14;-14;-13;-9;-16;0;-15;-5;-11;-4;-12;0;-4;-12;4;5;4;8;8;12;2;6;5;6;-6;-4;10;14;14;13;9;1;0;3;7;-6;-1;-6;6;10
J;-1;-3;-1;-9;-7;-5;0;0;-1;-2;-1;-1;-1;-8;-14;-16;-1;-4;-1;-8;0;-14;-15;-11;7;0;12;2;13;11;-1;-3;-3;-1;-4;-1;-4;-3;0;12;1;7;10;-3;5;4;-2;-2;0;-2
K;0;0;-5;4;4;2;5;1;2;-13;2;-7;-3;-5;-15;-13;-18;0;-2;-3;-2;-13;-10;-7;6;2;8;16;1;6;3;8;11;8;-5;-2;9;12;10;10;10;4;1;6;-5;7;8;9;8;7
L;2;0;-3;-7;0;4;2;0;1;-1;-13;-18;2;-15;-9;-7;-17;-1;0;0;-7;-1;-3;-2;0;0;9;4;-1;10;0;-2;0;3;2;0;1;2;11;17;2;6;6;2;2;2;3;4;2;5
M;-6;3;-8;-5;-5;-7;-1;-2;-11;-8;-10;-6;-4;-10;-8;-11;-2;-13;-8;-13;-16;-7;-17;-13;13;8;-1;5;9;1;1;-4;9;13;6;8;-3;-1;13;2;12;-1;-2;-1;9;-1;-3;-1;-1;-3
N;6;5;4;0;3;7;4;-7;-8;-9;-7;-10;-9;-1;-5;-2;-10;-7;-16;-12;-14;-15;-16;0;0;-3;17;12;10;0;6;1;4;2;10;2;2;-2;-2;3;8;-3;8;-6;-1;5;4;8;9;3
O;0;-4;2;3;-8;1;-4;0;-10;-10;-4;-4;-6;-16;-6;-1;-5;-2;-3;-5;-6;-10;-2;-15;0;-4;15;15;11;3;0;11;-2;9;-1;-3;-2;11;15;16;-1;2;7;0;10;-4;-4;2;0;0
P;-2;-2;0;-2;0;0;0;0;-2;-6;-3;-5;1;-6;-2;-4;-6;-14;-10;-1;-5;0;0;0;2;7;2;0;0;0;7;0;0;0;0;7;-1;9;5;9;6;5;-3;-2;-2;0;2;3;-7;0
Q;-8;7;7;5;-6;-3;-3;-4;-7;-11;-8;-8;-5;-13;-7;-9;-11;-15;-5;-7;-4;-6;-6;-6;5;6;5;9;3;2;5;3;6;10;7;9;6;3;2;4;4;8;4;7;8;0;-8;-8;5;4
R;-3;2;-4;-1;-3;-1;-2;-1;-3;-3;-16;-2;-11;-2;-10;0;-13;-3;-9;-15;-1;-16;-13;-10;11;-1;14;3;2;-2;0;0;-1;0;0;0;4;13;-1;1;0;-4;5;1;1;0;1;-5;-3;0
```

Code for MySQL

```
CREATE TABLE BlackBoxData
    (`Ball` varchar(1), `t1` int, `t2` int, `t3` int, `t4` int, `t5` int, `t6` int, `t7` int, `t8` int, `t9` int, `t10` int, `t11` int, `t12` int, `t13` int, `t14` int, `t15` int, `t16` int, `t17` int, `t18` int, `t19` int, `t20` int, `t21` int, `t22` int, `t23` int, `t24` int, `t25` int, `t26` int, `t27` int, `t28` int, `t29` int, `t30` int, `t31` int, `t32` int, `t33` int, `t34` int, `t35` int, `t36` int, `t37` int, `t38` int, `t39` int, `t40` int, `t41` int, `t42` int, `t43` int, `t44` int, `t45` int, `t46` int, `t47` int, `t48` int, `t49` int, `t50` int)
;

INSERT INTO BlackBoxData
    (`Ball`, `t1`, `t2`, `t3`, `t4`, `t5`, `t6`, `t7`, `t8`, `t9`, `t10`, `t11`, `t12`, `t13`, `t14`, `t15`, `t16`, `t17`, `t18`, `t19`, `t20`, `t21`, `t22`, `t23`, `t24`, `t25`, `t26`, `t27`, `t28`, `t29`, `t30`, `t31`, `t32`, `t33`, `t34`, `t35`, `t36`, `t37`, `t38`, `t39`, `t40`, `t41`, `t42`, `t43`, `t44`, `t45`, `t46`, `t47`, `t48`, `t49`, `t50`)
VALUES
    ('A', 1, 1, 1, -3, -1, -6, 0, 4, -5, 1, 1, -17, 0, -17, -18, -3, -14, -8, 0, -2, -3, -2, -1, -1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 15, -1, 0, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 1, 7, 13, -2, -1, -5, 4, -3, 7, 1, 1, 1),
    ('B', 5, -6, -7, 8, 5, 6, 6, 5, 6, -15, -12, -12, -10, -11, -4, -5, -16, -6, -6, -11, -10, -4, -7, -14, 0, -5, 16, 14, 12, 13, 10, 9, 10, 14, 9, 11, 11, 6, 12, 15, 11, 9, -7, 8, 11, -2, -6, -4, -4, 11),
    ('C', -7, 0, 5, 1, 1, 3, 1, 2, 5, 2, -11, -13, -8, -14, -17, -15, -12, -11, -13, -6, -11, -5, -8, -3, 8, 4, 7, 11, 6, 4, 8, 7, 7, 11, 1, 5, 5, 8, 6, 6, 5, 3, 3, 9, 12, 1, 6, 7, 4, 8),
    ('D', 4, 0, -2, -4, -2, -2, -5, 0, 0, 0, -6, -11, -2, -3, -11, -12, -8, -12, -4, -9, -8, -12, -5, -5, 10, 9, 3, 7, 4, 5, 4, 5, 3, 5, 8, 10, 14, 4, 8, 11, 7, 12, -4, -4, -6, -5, -5, -9, -6, -4),
    ('E', -5, 0, -6, -6, 7, 9, -8, -3, -9, -4, -2, -3, -7, -7, -1, -8, -9, -17, -15, -10, -9, -11, -11, -16, 12, 10, 13, 6, 5, 7, 9, 4, 2, 7, 5, 3, 7, 7, 3, 5, 14, 10, 9, 5, -4, 6, -7, -7, 7, 6),
    ('F', 3, 6, 8, -8, 6, 5, 3, 0, 3, -14, -15, -15, -15, -18, -12, -10, -4, -16, -14, -16, -13, -9, -9, -9, 9, 11, 10, 17, 16, 8, -3, 10, 13, 12, -3, 6, 13, 10, 9, 14, -3, -5, -5, 4, 3, 3, 5, 6, -5, 9),
    ('G', -4, -1, 0, 7, -9, 8, 0, -5, -4, -5, -9, -16, -14, -4, -13, -6, -7, -9, -12, -14, -15, -3, -14, -8, -1, -2, 11, 13, 7, 9, -2, -1, 8, -2, -2, 0, 12, -4, 7, -1, -2, 0, 2, 0, -3, 0, 0, -3, -2, -1),
    ('H', 8, -5, 6, 6, -4, -4, -6, -6, -6, -7, -5, -9, -12, -12, -3, -14, -3, -10, -7, -17, -17, -8, -12, -4, 3, 1, 6, 10, 14, -3, -4, -5, 12, 4, 4, 4, 8, 5, 4, 8, 3, 11, -6, 10, 6, 8, -9, 5, 3, 2),
    ('I', 7, 4, 3, 2, 2, 0, -7, 3, 4, -12, -14, -14, -13, -9, -16, 0, -15, -5, -11, -4, -12, 0, -4, -12, 4, 5, 4, 8, 8, 12, 2, 6, 5, 6, -6, -4, 10, 14, 14, 13, 9, 1, 0, 3, 7, -6, -1, -6, 6, 10),
    ('J', -1, -3, -1, -9, -7, -5, 0, 0, -1, -2, -1, -1, -1, -8, -14, -16, -1, -4, -1, -8, 0, -14, -15, -11, 7, 0, 12, 2, 13, 11, -1, -3, -3, -1, -4, -1, -4, -3, 0, 12, 1, 7, 10, -3, 5, 4, -2, -2, 0, -2),
    ('K', 0, 0, -5, 4, 4, 2, 5, 1, 2, -13, 2, -7, -3, -5, -15, -13, -18, 0, -2, -3, -2, -13, -10, -7, 6, 2, 8, 16, 1, 6, 3, 8, 11, 8, -5, -2, 9, 12, 10, 10, 10, 4, 1, 6, -5, 7, 8, 9, 8, 7),
    ('L', 2, 0, -3, -7, 0, 4, 2, 0, 1, -1, -13, -18, 2, -15, -9, -7, -17, -1, 0, 0, -7, -1, -3, -2, 0, 0, 9, 4, -1, 10, 0, -2, 0, 3, 2, 0, 1, 2, 11, 17, 2, 6, 6, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 2, 5),
    ('M', -6, 3, -8, -5, -5, -7, -1, -2, -11, -8, -10, -6, -4, -10, -8, -11, -2, -13, -8, -13, -16, -7, -17, -13, 13, 8, -1, 5, 9, 1, 1, -4, 9, 13, 6, 8, -3, -1, 13, 2, 12, -1, -2, -1, 9, -1, -3, -1, -1, -3),
    ('N', 6, 5, 4, 0, 3, 7, 4, -7, -8, -9, -7, -10, -9, -1, -5, -2, -10, -7, -16, -12, -14, -15, -16, 0, 0, -3, 17, 12, 10, 0, 6, 1, 4, 2, 10, 2, 2, -2, -2, 3, 8, -3, 8, -6, -1, 5, 4, 8, 9, 3),
    ('O', 0, -4, 2, 3, -8, 1, -4, 0, -10, -10, -4, -4, -6, -16, -6, -1, -5, -2, -3, -5, -6, -10, -2, -15, 0, -4, 15, 15, 11, 3, 0, 11, -2, 9, -1, -3, -2, 11, 15, 16, -1, 2, 7, 0, 10, -4, -4, 2, 0, 0),
    ('P', -2, -2, 0, -2, 0, 0, 0, 0, -2, -6, -3, -5, 1, -6, -2, -4, -6, -14, -10, -1, -5, 0, 0, 0, 2, 7, 2, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, -1, 9, 5, 9, 6, 5, -3, -2, -2, 0, 2, 3, -7, 0),
    ('Q', -8, 7, 7, 5, -6, -3, -3, -4, -7, -11, -8, -8, -5, -13, -7, -9, -11, -15, -5, -7, -4, -6, -6, -6, 5, 6, 5, 9, 3, 2, 5, 3, 6, 10, 7, 9, 6, 3, 2, 4, 4, 8, 4, 7, 8, 0, -8, -8, 5, 4),
    ('R', -3, 2, -4, -1, -3, -1, -2, -1, -3, -3, -16, -2, -11, -2, -10, 0, -13, -3, -9, -15, -1, -16, -13, -10, 11, -1, 14, 3, 2, -2, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 4, 13, -1, 1, 0, -4, 5, 1, 1, 0, 1, -5, -3, 0)
;
```

Code for MS SQL Server

```
CREATE TABLE BlackBoxData
    ([Ball] varchar(1), [t1] int, [t2] int, [t3] int, [t4] int, [t5] int, [t6] int, [t7] int, [t8] int, [t9] int, [t10] int, [t11] int, [t12] int, [t13] int, [t14] int, [t15] int, [t16] int, [t17] int, [t18] int, [t19] int, [t20] int, [t21] int, [t22] int, [t23] int, [t24] int, [t25] int, [t26] int, [t27] int, [t28] int, [t29] int, [t30] int, [t31] int, [t32] int, [t33] int, [t34] int, [t35] int, [t36] int, [t37] int, [t38] int, [t39] int, [t40] int, [t41] int, [t42] int, [t43] int, [t44] int, [t45] int, [t46] int, [t47] int, [t48] int, [t49] int, [t50] int)
;

INSERT INTO BlackBoxData
    ([Ball], [t1], [t2], [t3], [t4], [t5], [t6], [t7], [t8], [t9], [t10], [t11], [t12], [t13], [t14], [t15], [t16], [t17], [t18], [t19], [t20], [t21], [t22], [t23], [t24], [t25], [t26], [t27], [t28], [t29], [t30], [t31], [t32], [t33], [t34], [t35], [t36], [t37], [t38], [t39], [t40], [t41], [t42], [t43], [t44], [t45], [t46], [t47], [t48], [t49], [t50])
VALUES
    ('A', 1, 1, 1, -3, -1, -6, 0, 4, -5, 1, 1, -17, 0, -17, -18, -3, -14, -8, 0, -2, -3, -2, -1, -1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 15, -1, 0, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 1, 7, 13, -2, -1, -5, 4, -3, 7, 1, 1, 1),
    ('B', 5, -6, -7, 8, 5, 6, 6, 5, 6, -15, -12, -12, -10, -11, -4, -5, -16, -6, -6, -11, -10, -4, -7, -14, 0, -5, 16, 14, 12, 13, 10, 9, 10, 14, 9, 11, 11, 6, 12, 15, 11, 9, -7, 8, 11, -2, -6, -4, -4, 11),
    ('C', -7, 0, 5, 1, 1, 3, 1, 2, 5, 2, -11, -13, -8, -14, -17, -15, -12, -11, -13, -6, -11, -5, -8, -3, 8, 4, 7, 11, 6, 4, 8, 7, 7, 11, 1, 5, 5, 8, 6, 6, 5, 3, 3, 9, 12, 1, 6, 7, 4, 8),
    ('D', 4, 0, -2, -4, -2, -2, -5, 0, 0, 0, -6, -11, -2, -3, -11, -12, -8, -12, -4, -9, -8, -12, -5, -5, 10, 9, 3, 7, 4, 5, 4, 5, 3, 5, 8, 10, 14, 4, 8, 11, 7, 12, -4, -4, -6, -5, -5, -9, -6, -4),
    ('E', -5, 0, -6, -6, 7, 9, -8, -3, -9, -4, -2, -3, -7, -7, -1, -8, -9, -17, -15, -10, -9, -11, -11, -16, 12, 10, 13, 6, 5, 7, 9, 4, 2, 7, 5, 3, 7, 7, 3, 5, 14, 10, 9, 5, -4, 6, -7, -7, 7, 6),
    ('F', 3, 6, 8, -8, 6, 5, 3, 0, 3, -14, -15, -15, -15, -18, -12, -10, -4, -16, -14, -16, -13, -9, -9, -9, 9, 11, 10, 17, 16, 8, -3, 10, 13, 12, -3, 6, 13, 10, 9, 14, -3, -5, -5, 4, 3, 3, 5, 6, -5, 9),
    ('G', -4, -1, 0, 7, -9, 8, 0, -5, -4, -5, -9, -16, -14, -4, -13, -6, -7, -9, -12, -14, -15, -3, -14, -8, -1, -2, 11, 13, 7, 9, -2, -1, 8, -2, -2, 0, 12, -4, 7, -1, -2, 0, 2, 0, -3, 0, 0, -3, -2, -1),
    ('H', 8, -5, 6, 6, -4, -4, -6, -6, -6, -7, -5, -9, -12, -12, -3, -14, -3, -10, -7, -17, -17, -8, -12, -4, 3, 1, 6, 10, 14, -3, -4, -5, 12, 4, 4, 4, 8, 5, 4, 8, 3, 11, -6, 10, 6, 8, -9, 5, 3, 2),
    ('I', 7, 4, 3, 2, 2, 0, -7, 3, 4, -12, -14, -14, -13, -9, -16, 0, -15, -5, -11, -4, -12, 0, -4, -12, 4, 5, 4, 8, 8, 12, 2, 6, 5, 6, -6, -4, 10, 14, 14, 13, 9, 1, 0, 3, 7, -6, -1, -6, 6, 10),
    ('J', -1, -3, -1, -9, -7, -5, 0, 0, -1, -2, -1, -1, -1, -8, -14, -16, -1, -4, -1, -8, 0, -14, -15, -11, 7, 0, 12, 2, 13, 11, -1, -3, -3, -1, -4, -1, -4, -3, 0, 12, 1, 7, 10, -3, 5, 4, -2, -2, 0, -2),
    ('K', 0, 0, -5, 4, 4, 2, 5, 1, 2, -13, 2, -7, -3, -5, -15, -13, -18, 0, -2, -3, -2, -13, -10, -7, 6, 2, 8, 16, 1, 6, 3, 8, 11, 8, -5, -2, 9, 12, 10, 10, 10, 4, 1, 6, -5, 7, 8, 9, 8, 7),
    ('L', 2, 0, -3, -7, 0, 4, 2, 0, 1, -1, -13, -18, 2, -15, -9, -7, -17, -1, 0, 0, -7, -1, -3, -2, 0, 0, 9, 4, -1, 10, 0, -2, 0, 3, 2, 0, 1, 2, 11, 17, 2, 6, 6, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 2, 5),
    ('M', -6, 3, -8, -5, -5, -7, -1, -2, -11, -8, -10, -6, -4, -10, -8, -11, -2, -13, -8, -13, -16, -7, -17, -13, 13, 8, -1, 5, 9, 1, 1, -4, 9, 13, 6, 8, -3, -1, 13, 2, 12, -1, -2, -1, 9, -1, -3, -1, -1, -3),
    ('N', 6, 5, 4, 0, 3, 7, 4, -7, -8, -9, -7, -10, -9, -1, -5, -2, -10, -7, -16, -12, -14, -15, -16, 0, 0, -3, 17, 12, 10, 0, 6, 1, 4, 2, 10, 2, 2, -2, -2, 3, 8, -3, 8, -6, -1, 5, 4, 8, 9, 3),
    ('O', 0, -4, 2, 3, -8, 1, -4, 0, -10, -10, -4, -4, -6, -16, -6, -1, -5, -2, -3, -5, -6, -10, -2, -15, 0, -4, 15, 15, 11, 3, 0, 11, -2, 9, -1, -3, -2, 11, 15, 16, -1, 2, 7, 0, 10, -4, -4, 2, 0, 0),
    ('P', -2, -2, 0, -2, 0, 0, 0, 0, -2, -6, -3, -5, 1, -6, -2, -4, -6, -14, -10, -1, -5, 0, 0, 0, 2, 7, 2, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, -1, 9, 5, 9, 6, 5, -3, -2, -2, 0, 2, 3, -7, 0),
    ('Q', -8, 7, 7, 5, -6, -3, -3, -4, -7, -11, -8, -8, -5, -13, -7, -9, -11, -15, -5, -7, -4, -6, -6, -6, 5, 6, 5, 9, 3, 2, 5, 3, 6, 10, 7, 9, 6, 3, 2, 4, 4, 8, 4, 7, 8, 0, -8, -8, 5, 4),
    ('R', -3, 2, -4, -1, -3, -1, -2, -1, -3, -3, -16, -2, -11, -2, -10, 0, -13, -3, -9, -15, -1, -16, -13, -10, 11, -1, 14, 3, 2, -2, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 4, 13, -1, 1, 0, -4, 5, 1, 1, 0, 1, -5, -3, 0)
;
```

Comment: I would reverse score the `decreasing` values (along w/ making them negative) so that -1 is the smallest decrease & -9 is the largest decrease. Then the numbers will best follow the logic of the number line.

Comment: It's worth bearing in mind the large information loss that occurs b/c the black box only outputs these ordinal rankings (cf, [Efron's dice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nontransitive_dice#Efron.27s_dice)). That is, after 2 steps have passed, you no longer know which dice are larger than which (ie, die A may have a larger increase than B from 0->1, & B may have a larger increase than A from 1->2, at this point you have no way of knowing if A>B, A=B, or A<B). That fact complicates what could validly be visualized no matter what plot you end up using.

Comment: @gung Agreed, reverse scoring the `decreasing` values is more logical in order to analyze and plot trend.
And yes, there will be information loss on the eventual size of the balls.
But the final size of the balls is irrelevant to my goal.
I'm only interested in the trend of each ball.
Do have an idea for an approach in order to get those trends visualized?

Comment: You largely cannot visualize the trend because that information does not exist in your dataset. The smallest increase (ranked 7) in round 1 may be many fold greater than the largest increase (ranked 1) in round 2. I would simply track increased, neutral, or decreased, for each ball in each round.

Comment: @gung And what if we assume that the rank number is a quantification of the size increase/decrease?
Then you would have some form of trend information.
How would you visualize the trend in that case?
Also, would you normalize the data (say between -1 and +1) before plotting the trend?

Comment: "the final size of the balls is irrelevant to my goal. I'm only interested in the trend of each ball" may not be true. The measurements may be noisy, but any threshold on "significant change" is hidden in the black box (and quantization prevents canceling of random errors). For example say ball A has a change of 0.4 in each of 5 time steps, while ball B has a change of 1 and then -0.25 the next 4 steps. So net change is 2 for A and 0 for B. But if the black box only gives rounded numbers, then it will appear that A has 0 net change and B has +1.

Comment: @GeoMatt22 True, but it will show that ball A was growing for 5 time steps in a row, and that ball B has been shrinking most of the time. That information is relevant to me. I would have liked a line graph showing the increase/decrease trend, but I guess that's not possible considering the absolute size information is lacking, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't know anything about the magnitudes of the changes from one time slice to the next, I think the best you can do it just use the sign information from the ranking.

For instance, here's a heat map showing each ball's change over time. (blue = increase, gray = no change, red = decrease)

[image]

There appear to be some meaningful patterns or increasing and decreasing trends.

Based on your comment here are a few other variations without losing the relative ranks. I did transform the ranks so that the highest ranked item had the highest "Adj Rank" value and the lowest ranked item had the lowest "Adj Rank" value. For instance, a ranking of: 1, 2, 3, 0, -2, -1 becomes: 3, 2, 1, 0, -1, -2. My formula (using JMP):

```
If( :Rank == 0, 0,
    :Rank > 0, (:Name( "Maximum[Rank][Label]" ) - :Rank) + 1,
    (:Name( "Minimum[Rank][Label]" ) - :Rank) - 1
)
```

Here's the same heat map with the new Adj Rank instead of just the signed rank:

[image]

Here's a line for each ball using shaded regions for context showing the range of ranks for each time interval.

[image]

Here's all the Adj Ranks as overlaid lines over time.

[image]

It's hard to make out any particular ball, but if you can interact with it, you can highlight balls of interest and see how they do against the others. Here's A and B highlighted.

[image]

Comment: That visialization indeed shows the increasing/decreasing trend. However, the relative increase/decrease information is lost. After all, the black box returns the relative increase/decrease information (ranking). Is there a way to incorporate and visualize that?

Comment: I've added a few variations showing the actual ranks.